# How to convert array multidimensional in query string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, query-string

I have the following array with multiple arrays inside the object, how do I generate a query string, where the output should be.

Where `services` and `accountTypes` for example that are entries from array it becomes a key in query string.

The value in query string is the `id` from object in each array

Output should be for example

`services=10&services=30&accountTypes=20`

**Array**

```
[
  {
    "services": [
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "PIX"
      },
      {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Income"
      },
    ],
    "accountTypes": [
      {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "Digital Account"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**My function that I tried.**
I tried it with the encodeURIComponent as below, but it's generating undefined

```
const params = initialFilterDataJson.map((param: QueryParamsType) => {
    return encodeURIComponent(param.key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(param.id)
  })
  const queryString = params.join('&')
```

`http://localhost:3000/api/accounts?undefined=undefined`

Comment: Can you explain how you're getting from that input to `services=10&accountTypes=20`?

Comment: What if those sub arrays have multiple entries, like in your original question version? What should happen then? How will the query string look then?

Comment: @RenanBessa you did not answered the legit Trincot's question. Your data makes no sense. At least from the standpoint of what you're  trying to get from it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bavq8oyp/

Comment: @ChrisG did not work. In your solution, it only works for the first object inside the array, if there is more it doesn't work.

Comment: It was based on your input, which you keep changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not nesting deep enough in the data structure. You need to have nested loops, first to visit the objects in the outer array, then to visit the keys (with corresponding arrays) of such an object, and then to visit each inner object in such an array:

```js
const initialFilterDataJson = [{"services": [{"id": "10","name": "PIX"},{"id": "30","name": "Income"},],"accountTypes": [{"id": "20","name": "Digital Account"}]}];

const queryString = initialFilterDataJson.flatMap((param) =>
    Object.entries(param).flatMap(([key, arr]) =>
        arr.map(({id}) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(id))
    )
).join('&');

console.log(queryString);
```

Side note: some web servers can deal better with duplicate keys in the query string when they are suffixed with `[]`, like `services[]=10&services[]=20`.

Comment: Perfect @trincot, I still didn't know the flatmap. Thanks a lot